# providing argument to py2exe for creating exe file

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, python-import, setup.py

I have a python code that runs like this

```
python code.py version X
python code.py version Y 
python code.py version Z
```

I want to create three seperate exe's for this

I am using py2exe.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['code.py'])
```

This code will convert my python code to its exe , but I want to create three different exes with three different arguments. so all I want is that when I run my conversion code (python to exe) I could be able to tell it that its for X or Y or Z version exe.

I know I can do `code.exe version X` but I want to just have `code.exe` Any solution?

Thanks